# What can i do when a ex friend steals my Apple Watch from my home

Tags: theft

I used to have a friend and this “friend” stole my apple watch from my house the day before i was going to sell it. I have seached my whole house and have not found it im pretty sure its him because he has also taken my charger. By know i know he has sold it because he doesn’t own an iPhone what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

There are four main responses which are not illegal. First, you can forget about it. Second, you can try to persuade the person to return the watch. Third, you can sue him in court for recovery of the watch (which means you have to prove that he stole the watch). Small claims court is cheaper than hiring a lawyer and going to regular court, if you have small claims court in your jurisdiction. Finally, you can file a complaint with the police (who may or may not investigate and take action).